# junit vintage failed to discover tests: could not find method with name xxx

Tags: junit5, spock, junit-vintage

Im using `spockframework` and `junit5`, below is pom:

```xml
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When run class `Spec` (as same as Test of junit) i face below exception:

```sh
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:134)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Could not find method with name [should convert toEntity for worker] in class [com.myapp.converter.ApplicationConverterSpec].
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.lambda$lazyLoadJavaMethod$2(MethodSelector.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.lazyLoadJavaMethod(MethodSelector.java:174)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.getJavaMethod(MethodSelector.java:149)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.resolve(MethodSelectorResolver.java:36)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$0(MethodSelectorResolver.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.resolve(MethodSelectorResolver.java:30)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
    ... 13 more
```

this issue happen when i right-click to run single test case. and it's working fine if i run maven or whole test class. 
Not the big issue but i gonna find out why. 
Thanks

=====Edit=====
Here is my spec 
and now it working fine without any changes (just few time clean build and restart IDE \

```java
import com.fleetrecruitment.common.ApplicantDO
import com.fleetrecruitment.hsf.dto.masterdata.Gender
import com.fleetrecruitment.hsf.dto.masterdata.Photo
import com.fleetrecruitment.mapper.CommonMapperImpl
import com.fleetrecruitment.enums.GenderOption
import com.fleetrecruitment.hsf.dto.applicant.WorkerApplicant
import org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine
import spock.lang.Specification

class ApplicationConverterSpec extends Specification {
    private ApplicantConverter converter
    def setup(){
        converter = new ApplicantConverterImpl();
        converter.commonMapper = new CommonMapperImpl();
        converter.redmartCommonConverter = new RedmartCommonConverterImpl();
        JupiterTestEngine o = new JupiterTestEngine();
    }

    def "should convert toEntity for worker"(){
        when:
            ApplicantDO entity= converter.toEntity(givenWorker)
        then:
        with(entity){
            name == expEntity.name
            phoneNumber == expEntity.phoneNumber
            gender == expEntity.gender
            with(idPhotos.get(0)){
                bizType == expEntity.idPhotos.get(0).bizType
                name == expEntity.idPhotos.get(0).name
            }
        }
        where:
            givenWorker << [
                    new WorkerApplicant( name: "Trung.do", phoneNumber: "123456", gender: GenderOption.FEMALE,
                    idPhotos: "[{\"name\": \"abc.jpg\", \"bizType\": \"logistics-fleet-recruitment\", \"ossObjectKey\": \"268d129bcd894a25a44849f26d44bba3_3e8cd422be83474ab992b9d41018840f.jpg\"},{}]" )
            ]

            expEntity << [
                   new ApplicantDO(name: "Trung.do", phoneNumber: "123456", gender: Gender.FEMALE,
                           idPhotos: [new Photo(bizType:"logistics-fleet-recruitment", name: "abc.jpg")]
                   )
            ]

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, you could also share the source for the failing test `ApplicationConverterSpec`. I would guess that there is a `@Test` annotation for the Spock spec, if so just remove it.

Comment: When asking questions and receiving comments or answers, please be polite enough to provide feedback too, after someone spent time trying to help you. So please either reply to Leonard's comment, if your problem is solved, or edit the question, showing your Spock specification and ideally also the code under test. Thanbk you very much.

Comment: hi @LeonardBrünings, sorry for late reply, the issue has gone without any fix. may be IDE cached issue somewhere. In deed there are no `@Test` on my spec. Thanks for your help